# How to get a border around a text for a JButton

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a sort of a chess board for class (for Java).  Our teacher wants us to make each square on the chess board a button, and he provided us with an idea of how the buttons should look.  Empty squares obviously need to be either plain black or plain white.  The issue arises when there's a piece on the squares.  Our teacher wants us to use text to note what pieces are on what squares, and he wants the text to be either black or white depending on whose piece it is.  Since we can't put white text over a white background, he suggests that when a piece is on a square, we change the square's color to grey.  I'm not a fan.  Is it possible to make some sort of border around the text so, for example, I can have a white border over black letters and a black border over white letters?  Or a pink border around all letters?

Comment: did you manage to work it out?

Comment: Not yet.  I might just go for making the white pieces pink and the black pieces blue, or something along those lines.

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the font color for the button.

To do this, use:

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

To make the font white, and:

```
b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

to make it black again. You can call a function which has that code in it whenever you need to change the writing color.